# Inner ng-repeat is skipping the first item of my array, and putting them into the last html element

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a JSON array that I'm trying to convert and display as HTML using angular's ng-repeat.

My JSON is of the form:

```
data:{
thing_one:[{
       id:1,
       fields:[{ .... }]
    },
    {
       id:2,
       fields:[{ .... }]
    }],
separate_thing:[{
       id:1,
       fields:[{ .... }]
    },
    {
       id:2,
       fields:[{ .... }]
    }]
}
```

And in my controller for that page:

I have:

```
MockFields.get(function(data){
    $scope.thing_one = data.thing_one;
    $scope.separate_thing = data.separate_thing;
}
```

And a stripped down version of my html is:

```
<div class="details">
    <div class="my_header">
        <h2>Thing 1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="thing_one">
        <dynamic-form fields="thing_1[0].fields"><dynamic-form>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="details">
    <div class="my_header">
        <h2>Separate Thing</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="separate_thing" ng-repeat="thing in separate_thing>
        <dynamic-form fields="thing.fields"><dynamic-form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where `<dynamic-form>` is a custom directive, where I repeat over my fields, and use an `ng-switch on=...` to pick a field type. It looks a little something like this (again cut down)

```
<div ng-repeat='field in fields track by field.order'>
    <label>{{field.display}}</label>
    <span ng-switch on='field.fieldtype'>
        <span ng-switch-when="text">
            <input type="text"/>
        </span>
        <span ng-switch-when="....">
            <input type="...."/>
        </span>
         .
         .
         .
         .
    </span>
</div>
```

What I'm seeing however is that all of my fields from both `thing`s in `separate_thing` are in the last `<dynamic-form>` and the first one is empty.

This is what I see when I inspect that element/section of the DOM:

```
<div class="details">
    <div class="my_header">
        <h2>Separate Thing</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="separate_thing" ng-repeat="thing in separate_thing></div>
    <div class="separate_thing" ng-repeat="thing in separate_thing>
        <div>
             <label>Foo from separate thing 1</label>
             <input type="text">
             .....
       </div>
       <div>
             <label>Foo from separate thing 2</label>
             <input type="text">
             .....
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is this an optimization from angular? Or have I done something wrong? I'm a little lost as I've not seen any errors from my code.

Why is it pushing all my sub-objects (fields) to the last element?

Comment: @Werlang I can try and make one, but my plnkr-fu is weak, and I can't copy and paste the code from where it is. I'll give it a try when I have some time.

Comment: I'd suggest you them to inspect the scope of ng-repeat's element on console: select it on chrome then type `angular.element($0).scope()`

Comment: @Werlang I'm stuck on Firefox 10. :'(

Comment: @Werlang I've managed to inspect the scope of the page with `console.log($scope.separate_thing[0])` and it gives me the write JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might have been a bug.

Angular directives fail to compile when they have multiple elements without a containing element, which my previous set up had (via ng-repeat)

Instead inside my directive, I've now wrapped the div with `ng-repeat` inside an out div.

So I now have:

```
<div>
    <div ng-repeat='field in fields track by field.order'>
        <label>{{field.display}}</label>
        <span ng-switch on='field.fieldtype'>
            <span ng-switch-when="text">
                <input type="text"/>
            </span>
            <span ng-switch-when="....">
                <input type="...."/>
            </span>
             .
             .
             .
             .
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And it all seems happy.